# Can I point Firefox at the Flash plugin for IE 8?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, flash, youtube

Windows XP Pro, IE 8, Firefox 14.0.1

I have the stack above. I can't watch YouTube in Firefox, because Firefox doesn't have the Flash plugin and I don't have admin rights to install it. However, I do have Flash on my system as IE 8 runs YouTube just fine.

Is there a way I can tell Firefox where to find Flash on my system?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Firefox and IE use two different plugin architectures: Firefox uses NPAPI while IE uses ActiveX. These two are not compatible with each other, so it's impossible for Firefox to use an IE plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have rights to run the Flash installation program to hook up flashy web pages in the 'fox. Luckily, when you're on a computer that already has Flash installed, you can enjoy Flash on the go with a simple trick that enables Flash in Firefox.

Copy these two files: `flashplayer.xpt` and `NPSWF32.dll` from the default install directory usually

> c:\Windows\system32\Macromedia\Flash\

Paste them in the following folder in your installation of Firefox

> \App\firefox\plugins\

Restart Firefox and check out a page with Flash content on it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The user does not have the ability to get flashplayer.xpt installed on his computer.